# How to compare that two Traversables contain exactly the same elements?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I want to check if two `Traversable`s contain the same elements without respect to their order.

So, I tried it myself and wrote the following simple example:

```
implicit val l = 3
implicit def equality(implicit l: Int) = new Equality[String] {
  override def areEqual(a: String, b: Any): Boolean = (a, b) match {
    case (_, b: Int) => a.toInt == b
  }
}

"Test" should "check how equality works" in {
    List("1") should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1) //Fine
    List("1", "2") should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2) //Fine
    List("1", "2", "3") should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2, 3) //Fine
    List("1", "2", "2") should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2, 2) //Error
    List("2", "1") should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2) //Error
}
```

As the [***the documentation***](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithAggregations) says:

> The "`contain theSameElementsAs`" syntax lets you assert that two
>   aggregations contain the same objects

It shouldn't take duplication and order into account. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fundamental issue is that the `equality` relation is not reflective, as one would expect. That is if `x == y` then `y == x`.

Scalacheck tries to [count the number of repetitions](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/d40d278f2bb8e73431b942d87881fb6dbab75cb9/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/enablers/Aggregating.scala) in target collection using the `equality` function provided.

When it meets `equality(2,2)`, `tryEquality` [fails internally with a `ClassCastException`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/d40d278f2bb8e73431b942d87881fb6dbab75cb9/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/enablers/Aggregating.scala#L128), defaulting the comparison to false.

Bottom line: `Equality` needs to be reflective (as good old math dictates) in order to have the expected result.

Comment: Completely agree. Just didn't know the exact contract of the Equality[L].

Answer (score 0):

Use `Int` List instead of String List in the left hand side.

```
 "Test" should "check how equality works" in {
    List(1) should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1) //Fine
    List(1, 2) should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2) //Fine
    List(1, 2, 3) should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2, 3) //Fine
    List(1, 2, 2) should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2, 2) //Fine
    List(2, 1) should contain theSameElementsAs Vector(1, 2) //Fine
  }
```

output:

```
[info] Test
[info] - should check how equality works
[info] Run completed in 354 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

Comment: Ah, that's not exactly what I wanted :). It indeed works that way if we don't provide an implicit Equality. But if we do, it doesn't... I just didn't like exposing my specific case with all its complications...